# "Bit-masking” condition is not returning correct value

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, data-masking

The bit masking is not returning the correct value

I am trying to solve this condition and I am always getting 8 as a return value. I am not sure for the condition of bit manipulation is read.

```
int outputbyte[3] = {10,11,12};
int result;
result = (outputbyte[1] & 11)?8:0;
printf("\nMasked value is: %d", result);
```

I can’t understand how this condition is getting true (outputbyte[1] & 11)?

Comment: Do you expect `11&11` to be false?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int outputbyte[3] = {10,11,12};
result = (outputbyte[1] & 11)?8:0;
```

this

```
result = (outputbyte[1] & 11)?8:0  /* (outputbyte[1] & 11) results in true hence 8 assigned to result */
```

is ternary operator i.e first *operand-1* i.e `(outputbyte[1] & 11)?8:0)` gets evaluated and if it results in *non zero*, *operand-2* i.e `8` gets assigned with `result` else *operand-3* i.e `0` gets assigned to `result`.

```
outputbyte[1] ==> 11   => 0000 1011
                                  & ( bitwise AND operator)
                  11   => 0000 1011
                         -----------
                          0000 1011   => 11 i.e nonzero i.e condition true i.e 11 gets assigned to result
                         -----------
```

I hope you are aware of truth table of bitwise AND `&` operator which is

```
A   B    A&B
------------
0   0     0
0   1     0
1   0     0
1   1     1
```